# Sci-fi trilogy that includes a catholic priest, Dwarves, and creatures that cannot feel pain that are used as weapons

Tags: story-identification, books

I read the series a few years ago and I can't remember its name or any of the character names in it. I remembered it starts in New York and a hole opens up in the sky above a baseball stadium. A vine comes down from the hole and creatures start spilling into Earth from the other world.

The rest of it is a little fuzzy for me, but the ending had the main antagonist having his body's molecules being forcibly ripped apart, and he has to use his own strength to pull himself back together. He also slowly stops Earth's rotation over time.

Comment: How come none of the stuff mentioned in the title made it into your question? What about the priest? Catholic? Satanist? What about the drawers? Are they articles of clothing, or sliding boxes, or draftspersons? How are the numb creatures used as weapons? Do you swing them like clubs, or hurl them as projectiles, or what?

Comment: If you described the first hole as opening up in the ground in Central Park, and nasty supernatural creatures flying up out of the hole and attacking people, then I'd think you were referring to *Nightworld* by F. Paul Wilson. A former Catholic priest was one of the characters, and the sun was rising later than it should and setting earlier than it should, day by day, all over the world (somehow!); hence the title of the book. If the forces of evil were not quickly defeated, it would be dark all day, every day, regardless of "normal physics" -- hence a world of endless night, or "Nightworld."

Comment: This reminds me of a Ben Bova thing I was too lazy to return to SFBC. Just as I am too lazy to go up and dig it out of a box at the moment.